# Proving euler's reflection formula

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

We can use the relationship:
$$\beta(j,k)=\dfrac{\Gamma(j)\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(j+k)} ; j,k >0 $$

Setting $j=z$ and $k=1-z$, we obtain :
$$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \beta(z,1-z); 0 < z < 1$$

Now, $\beta(z,1-z)$=$\int_0^1x^{z-1}(1-x)^{-z}dx$ = $2\int_0^{\pi/2}tan^{n}(t)dt$, after the substitution $x=sin^2(t)$ and $n=2z-1$

Next, we define $I_{n}=\int_0^{\pi/2}tan^{n}(t)dt$ ; $-1 < n < 1 $.

$I_{n}=\int_0^{\pi/2}tan^{n}(t)dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}tan^{n-2}(t)(sec^2(t)-1)dt = \int_0^{\pi/2}tan^{n-2}(t)sec^2(t)dt - I_{n-2}$. After the substitution $tan(t)=u$, we get:
$$ I_{n} + I_{n-2} = \int_0^\infty u^{n-2}du$$

However, the limits pose a problem, as the integral evaluates $\infty$ [keeping in mind the domain of $n$]: Which is incorrect. We can see this through reverse engineering: $I_{n}$ should be equal  to $\dfrac{\pi}{2sin(\pi z)}=\dfrac{\pi}{2sin(\pi (\dfrac{n+1}{2})}=\dfrac{\pi}{2} sec\dfrac{n\pi}{2}$. Therefore,

$I_{n} + I_{n-2} =\dfrac{\pi}{2} sec\dfrac{n\pi}{2} + \dfrac{\pi}{2} sec\dfrac{(n-2)\pi}{2} =0$.

Which leads me to two questions, the major one being in bold:

1. What have I done wrong to obtain $\infty$ as the value of the integral instead of $0$?
2. Even if I somehow prove $I_{n}+I_{n-2}=0$, I don't see how I can extrapolate the value of $I_{n}$ from this. The only conclusion I can draw from this is that $I_{n}$ *might be* some function of $sin^{l}(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+k)$, where $l$ is odd, since increasing n by 2 adds pi to the argument which flips the sign. Which seems to suggest that my approach isn't correct, and so,
   **Is there any other method which allows me to prove that $I_{n}=\dfrac{\pi}{2} sec\dfrac{n\pi}{2}$?**

Comment: The problem is is when you split $I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{n-2}{t}(\sec^2{t}-1)\,dt$ into $\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{n-2}{t}(\sec^2{t})\,dt$ and $-\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{n-2}{t}\,dt$. Neither of these two integrals exist separately.

Comment: Restrict $z \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ since the relation is symmetric.  This way $n \in \left(-1,0\right)$ which provides a convergent integral.